# Force Notepad++ to not remember case-sensitiviy for find operations

Tags: notepad++, search, find, text-editors, find-and-replace

Notepad++ will remember the state of the ***Match Case*** setting in the Find dialog box between sessions.

For my uses, this is not desirable *(at all!)* because it is easy to not notice that it is checked, causing all sorts of problems.

Is there a simple way to force Notepad++ to ***not*** remember the state of that checkbox and to always default to *case-insensitive* find operations?

Comment: edit shortcut to run a batch edit Notepad++.xml file to search and *replace** then launch App      <FindHistory nbMaxFindHistoryPath="10" nbMaxFindHistoryFilter="10" nbMaxFindHistoryFind="10" nbMaxFindHistoryReplace="10" matchWord="no" **matchCase="no"** wrap="yes" directionDown="yes" fifRecuisive="yes" fifInHiddenFolder="no" dlgAlwaysVisible="no" fifFilterFollowsDoc="no" fifFolderFollowsDoc="no" searchMode="0" transparencyMode="1" transparency="150" dotMatchesNewline="no" />

Comment: @TonyStewart Why don't you write an answer? At least your code will be readable ...

Comment: thats not a soution, just the string in app setup